# Is there a RAW monster that can create large quantities of water without magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, special-abilities

I've asked the google and can't find anything, and I feel as though I've looked pretty deeply into the monster manual, but I'm wondering if there's a monster that can naturally create large quantities of water. I.E. not using magic or items. I'm thinking of a water elemental, however that seems to be the only thing I can find. I'm looking for something a little weaker, to throw at a level 3 party of 3 PC's with no healing capabilities. If I can't find anything I'll make a small homebrew. The thing I'm trying to do is create almost a trap out of creatures, that they can stop by killing off all the creatures. If they fail to kill them the party can be in a bad situation, but if they kill them all the room opens a drain and they're free to collect the treasure locked in the next room by the water pressure.

Comment: I feel like this will be unanswerable because "create large amount of substance from essentially nothing" and "not using magic" are at odds with each other. If we rule out magic that essentially leaves us with real world physics and chemistry, in neither of which you can really pull stuff out of thin air. Also, this feels like an XY problem: Can you elaborate on why specifically can they not be magical? I don't see anything explaining why you couldn't achieve the scenario you're planning with simply magically created water.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that in the *Monster Manual*, all the ways an elemental can come in to existence described inherently involve magic, so I wouldn't really call them non-magical either. Not to mention, RAW, water elementals don't really have ways to *create* water, they are just made out of it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### There is no such monster

Like always it is hard to prove a negative, but I am pretty confident that there is no low-CR monster that has the ability to create large volumes of water without the use of magic. Not even a [water elemental](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17051-water-elemental) can do that, they are made out of water, but they lack a feature in their stat block that would create water in large amounts.

There are good reasons for this. Any item or creature that can do this (like a [decanter of endless water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4615-decanter-of-endless-water)) can potentially be abused given enough time to flood entire dungeons or massively disrupt the economy in a desert setting (as explained in the [Sane Magical Items](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XAiXpOfz9cMWt1RTBicmpmUDg/view?resourcekey=0-ceHUken0_UhQ3Apa6g4SJA) price list, a third party source that tries to price items by actual power, and assigns a value of 135,000 gp to this Uncommon item).

You'll have to make a small homebrew.

Comment: Ah yes, flooding the whole dungeon plan. Before decanters of endless water we had to do it the old fashioned way: by redirecting a river!

Comment: @Negdo you're inspiring dangerous dwarf fortress x DnD themed crossover ideas in my head :)